# Is there any way to get whether button is checked or not in tkinter without passing any command to button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

```
if x ==0:
    MD_checkvar = IntVar()
    MD_Text = Checkbutton(MD_Frame, text="  Text  ", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var1, command=ABcfunc)
    MD_Text.place(x=100, y=200)
    
    MD_checkvar_FN = IntVar()
    MD_fileName = Checkbutton(MD_Frame, text="File Name", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var2)
    MD_fileName.place(x=170, y=200)
```

Is there any way to get the `var2.get()` status `0\1` without defining the command in `2nd checkbox`?

Comment: You can call `.get()` on the vars any time you want.  A `command=` option is the most convenient way to know that the state has changed, and therefore you might want to call `.get()`, but it's not required.

Comment: You mean to say i can call var2.get() to get the status without defining any command ??

Comment: Of course.  What problem were you imagining there might be?

Comment: @Anuj Please accept the answer if you find it helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @jasonharper mention in the comments,

> You can call `.get()` on the vars any time you want. A `command=` option is the most convenient way to know that the state has changed, and therefore you might want to call `.get()`, but it's not required.

This is true. You can call `var2.get()` whenever you want.

Just for your reference, an example using [`.get()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method):

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

window.title("Window")
window.geometry("500x500")

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()

def print_contents():
    print(e.get())

b = Button(window, text = "Submit", command = print_contents)
b.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps!